# Bad Request when posting JSON to Flask endpoint in unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, flask, flask-jwt

I found a load of questions about people trying to post JSON to a Flask app, but none of those are quite the problem I have here.

I have a simple REST API, built using Flask and Flask-JWT, which is working fine through a browser, but I've hit a block with my unit tests.  The app is an App Engine app and runs fine on the local dev server and on App Engine.  I'm running my unit tests with `python -m unittest <module>`.

I have a basic Flask app created using a simple factory:

```
def create_app(name=__name__, cfg):
    app = Flask(name)
    app.config.update(cfg)

    CORS(app)
    JWT(app, auth_handler, identity_handler)

    @app.route('/api/v1/ping', methods=['GET'])
    def handle_ping():
        return jsonify({'message': 'pong'})

    # other routes ...
```

In the above, `JWT` expects an [`authentication_handler`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/index.html#flask_jwt.JWT.authentication_handler), which I have implemented:

```
def auth_handler(identity, secret):
    # validate identity and secret
    return User(...)
```

My client is Angular.js so I am posting JSON to this endpoint. This is all working fine in a browser, or with curl:

```
$ curl -H "content-type:application/json" -d '{"username":"jackripper@example.com","password":"crm114"}'   http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth
```

giving me a `200 OK` and an access token in the response.

My simple test cases go something like this:

```
conf = {
     'DEBUG': False,
    'TESTING': True,
    'SECRET_KEY': 'MoveAlongTheresNothingToSeeHere',
    'JWT_AUTH_URL_RULE': '/api/v1/auth'
}

class FlaskRouteTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        api = factory.create_app(__name__, conf)
        self.app = api.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def testRoute(self):
        # This test works just fine
        resp = self.app.get('/api/v1/ping')
        self.assertEqual(resp.status, "200 OK", "Status should be 200, was %s" % resp.status)

    def testAuth(self):
        # This test does not work
        resp = self.app.post('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth',
                         data="{'username': 'jackripper@example.com', 'password': 'crm114'}",
                         content_type='application/json', charset='UTF-8')
        self.assertEqual(resp.status, "200 OK", "Status should be 200, was %s" % resp.status)
```

The plain old `GET` test (`testRoute()`) works just fine but `testAuth()` gives me a `400 Bad Request` and I can't figure out why.

If I look at the *werkzeug* `environ` immediately before it sends the request to my Flask app, I see this:

```
{
 'SERVER_PORT': '8080',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': '',
 'wsgi.input': <_io.BytesIO object at 0x111fa8230>,
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
 'HTTP_HOST': 'localhost:8080',
 'PATH_INFO': '/api/v1/auth',
 'wsgi.multithread': False,
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/json',
 'HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH': '53',
 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '53',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0),
 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost',
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x10fd2d1e0>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
 'flask._preserve_context': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'CONTENT_TYPE': u'application/json'
}
```

So, the content-type is correctly set and if I read the contents of the `wsgi.input` (`BytesIO.getvalue()`) I see `{'username': 'jackripper@example.com', 'password': 'crm114'}`

The request seems to be failing somewhere *before* it even hits my `auth_handler`, so somewhere in werkzeug or Flask.

- The werkzeug `EnvironBuilder` interprets the data as a `str` and converts it to a `BytesIO` stream - I don't know if this is expected.
- I've tried POSTing data both as a string: `data="{'username': 'jackripper@example.com', 'password': 'password'}"` and as a dict: `data={'username': 'jackripper@example.com', 'password': 'password'}`, but it seems to make no difference.

**So, my question**:
How do I post JSON to an endpoint in a unit test with `Flask.test_client()`?  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Perhaps your JSON is malformed?  (I think JSON requires double-quotes, not single, around the individual variables.)  Try creating a python dict with the values and then pass `json.dumps(mydict)` as the `data=` parameter in your `self.app.post()` call.

Comment: Yes, that worked too (see Martijn's response).  I somehow completely overlooked the fact that the data in my curl request was quoted differently (correctly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not posting valid JSON:

```
data="{'username': 'jackripper@example.com', 'password': 'crm114'}",
```

Note the single quotes. JSON uses **double** quotes; the following would be valid JSON:

```
data='{"username": "jackripper@example.com", "password": "crm114"}',
```

Comment: Thanks! So, yes... it seems I was missing something blindingly obvious. I made the mistake just enclosing the existing dict literal in double quotes.  That'll teach me.

Comment: @tx802: you could avoid mistakes like these by using `json.dumps()` in your test. ;-)

Comment: I will do now for sure!